# Is the following a scoping issue when trying to use Tee-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Environment:
Windows Server 2016
Windows 10 Pro
PowerShell 5.1

$myVariable is empty, I think and I'm expecting there to be a string value.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName WKSP000D1E3F -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock { 
sqlcmd -E -Q "select top 1 FirstName from customers" -d database1 -S "(localdb)\ProjectsV13" | Tee-Object -Variable myVariable
}

Write-Host $myVariable
```

Comment: Capture the output from `Invoke-Command` instead of `Tee-Object` inside the scriptblock, like this `$captureOutputHere = Invoke-Command -ComputerNa......`

Comment: To answer the title, yes it's a scoping issue. `Tee-Object -Variable` only sets the variable in the "local" scope. In this case, that scope is both inside the script block *and* on the remote computer

Answer (score 1):

[Cpt.Whale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7411885/cpt-whale) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment: **you fundamentally cannot set *local* variables from a script block being executed *remotely***  (via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) 
`-ComputerName`) - you must use *output* from the script block to communicate data back to the caller.

While **you could apply [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) *locally*** instead (`Invoke-Command ... | Tee-Object`), there's a **simpler solution**, which **works with *all* cmdlets**, including cmdlet-like ([advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)) functions and scripts:

Use the **[common `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) to capture a cmdlet's output in a self-chosen variable *while passing that output through***:

```sh
# Note the `-OutVariable myVariable` part
# and that the variable name must be specified *without* a leading "$"
# Output is still being passed through.
Invoke-Command -OutVariable myVariable -ComputerName WKSP000D1E3F -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock { 
  sqlcmd -E -Q "select top 1 FirstName from customers" -d database1 -S "(localdb)\ProjectsV13"
}

# $myVariable now contains the captured content.
```

By contrast, if you want **to capture output *only*, without also passing it through** (to the display, by default), you can heed [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)'s advice and **simply assign the `Invoke-Command` call to your variable (`$myVariable = Invoke-Command ...`)**.

Notes re `-OutVariable`(`-ov`):

- As shown above, and as shown with `Tee-Object -Variable` in your question, the name of the self-chosen target variable must be specified *without a leading `$`*, e.g. `-OutVariable var`, not `Out-Variable $var`; if you did the latter, the *value of a preexisting `$var` variable* (if defined) would be used as the variable name.
- Unlike directly captured output, the target variable *always* receives array(-like) data, specifically, an instance of the [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) class - even if only *one* output object is present; e.g.:

  ```sh
  # -> 'types: v1: String vs. v2: ArrayList'
  $v1 = Write-Output -OutVariable v2 'one'
  "types: v1: $($v1.GetType().Name) vs. v2: $($v2.GetType().Name)"
  ```

  - That is, while directly capturing output captures a single output object as-is, and multiple ones in a regular PowerShell array (of type `[object[]]`, `-OutVariable` *always* creates an `ArrayList` - see [GitHub issue #3154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154) for a discussion of this inconsistency.

---

**With commands that do *not* support `-OutVariable`**, namely *simple* scripts and functions as well as *external programs*:

- To pass the output through in *streaming* fashion, i.e. as it becomes available, pipe to `Tee-Object -Variable`; e.g.:

  ```sh
  # Passes output through as it is being emitted.
  some.exe | Tee-Object -Variable myVariable
  ```
- Otherwise - i.e. if it is acceptable to *collect all output first*, before passing it through - simply enclose an assignment statement in  [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) to pass its value through - this approach *performs better* than `Tee-Object -Variable`; e.g.:

  ```sh
  # Collects all output first, then passes it through.
  ($myVariable = some.exe)
  ```